# Can't Install Fedora or Ubuntu in 64-Bit WIndows Virtual PC

Tags: windows-7

Trying to run a simple default install of the latest Ubuntu or Fedora on 64-bit Windows 7. The install gets to the graphical portion of the install and shuts down Virtual PC completely without any messages . . . am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the Windows built in virtual PC or a third part?

Comment: I'm using the built-in Virtual PC with Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Virtual PC? Try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).